# Teradata error 2620 - The format or data contains a bad character

Tags: sql, teradata

I ran the below code :

```
select cast(meas_value as float) as temperature
from meas_table
where  temperature < cast('96.80' as float) 
    or temperature  > cast('100.90' as float)
```

I get the error

> 2620: The format or data contains bad character.

The temperature values are - 102.5, 98, 99.5, 97.7

Comment: Is `select cast(meas_value as float) as temperature
from meas_table
where  cast(meas_value as float) < cast('96.80' as float) 
    or cast(meas_value as float) > cast('100.90' as float)` working for you?

Comment: What datatype has `meas_value`? If it's a VarChar use `select * from meas_table where to_number(meas_value) is null` to find bad data. Why don't you simply write `96.80` instead of `cast('96.80' as float)`?